# How can I fill the area between the lines (like the below picture)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill the area between four lines which are shown in the picture.

[image]

‎‎

```
\documentclass{standalone}‎‎
‎\usepackage{tikz}‎‎‎
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\begin{tikzpicture}‎[scale=1.3]
‎‎\draw[ ] (1,0)‎ -‎-(3,0);‎
‎‎‎\draw[ ] (1,1)‎ -‎-(3.3,3.3);
\draw[line cap=round, line width=0.2mm, domain=0:0.785, variable=\t, samples=100, yshift=0mm, rotate around={0:(0,0)}]plot[fixed point arithmetic] ({\t r}:{1.5*exp(0.577*\t)});‎
\draw[line cap=round, line width=0.2mm, domain=0:0.785, variable=\t, samples=100, yshift=0mm, rotate around={0:(0,0)}]
        plot[fixed point arithmetic] ({\t r}:{2.7*exp(0.577*\t)});‎       

  ‎\end{tikzpicture}‎
‎\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code is not possible to compile ... it contain hidden characters or something else which prevent cause errors in compilation. Please check you uploaded code.

Comment: Ok, the code is corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

meanwhile I rewrote your code from scratch (do you realy need so many options doing nothing?):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3]
\draw [fill=orange!30,
       variable=\t, samples=100]
            plot[domain=0:0.785] ({ \t r}:{1.5*exp(0.577*\t)})  --
            plot[domain=0.785:0] ({\t r}:{2.7*exp(0.577*\t)});
\draw   (1,0) -- (3.3,0)
        ({0.785 r}:1.3) -- + ({0.785 r}:3.3);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This MWE gives:

[image]

Is this what you looking for?

Comment: Glad to hear this! I just slightly change code, now use your original domains and drawing straight lines is more accurate.